# How to create Multilevel dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm wondering about how can I create multilevel dropdown menu using bootstrap 5 and vanila js I create this example base on bootstrap 5 dropdowns component documentation. but it didn't displayed when I clicked on.

the issue is about vanila js if anyone
has any idea to achieve that!

**Here my code :**

```js
var myDropdown = document.getElementById('myDropdown')
myDropdown.addEventListener('show.bs.dropdown', function () {})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Bootstrap 5</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container py-5">
    <h1 class="mb-4">Multilevel Dropdowns With Button :</h1>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Multilevel Dropdown link
                    </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown dropend">
          <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="multilevelDropdownMenu1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Multilevel Action 1</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="multilevelDropdownMenu1">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown dropend">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="multilevelDropdownMenu1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Multilevel Action 2</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="multilevelDropdownMenu2">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**[Live Example](https://codepen.io/themes4all/pen/gOggbYb)**

Comment: Your example works as expected. It displays just fine.

As far as using normal js and not jquery, this is a lot of code, you will want to use something per-existing most likely. Here is a link that describes this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Comment: based on my JS example how can I make the multilevel dropdown menu displayed when my mouse move over the dropdown item link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added an eventlistener for every dropdown-toggle for hiding/showing the submenus and then it worked. Instead of click you can of course use it with 'mouseover' (just replace 'click' in the eventhandler):

```js
var myDropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-toggle')
for (i=0; i<myDropdown.length; i++) {
    myDropdown[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var el = this.nextElementSibling;
        el.style.display = el.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <title>Bootstrap 5</title>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container py-5">
        <h1 class="mb-4">Multilevel Dropdowns With Button :</h1>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Multilevel Dropdown link
                        </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown dropend">
              <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="multilevelDropdownMenu1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Multilevel Action 1</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="multilevelDropdownMenu1">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown dropend">
                  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="multilevelDropdownMenu1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Multilevel Action 2</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="multilevelDropdownMenu2">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </body>

</html>
```